# How to use Navigation graph for Activity?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation, navgraph

As we all know navGraph contains `fragments screen` and `strings(action)` that connect two `fragments`, this navGraph can be hosted on NavHostFragment inside an activity XML.

So in the same fashion can we navigate between `activities`?

Comment: Nope... Nav graph only for fragments

Comment: send parameter from one activity to other activity and navigate fragment on base of parameters